# Unnumbered chapter in toc and heading

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, koma-script

I'm writing a thesis using `scrreprt` and want the preface to appear as an unnumbered chapter. When I use

```
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
```

I get the correct entry in the table of contents, but the heading is not set correctly by `srclayer-scrpage`. Instead I get the title of the previous chapter in the heading, which happens to be "List of Figures" in my case.

I guess I could manually refresh the chapter title for the heading as well, but probably there is a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course I figured it out a few minutes after posting the question…

The right command to use is `\addchap` provided by KOMA-Script for `scrbook` and `scrreprt`. Using

```
\addchap{Preface}
```

I get an unnumbered chapter that appears in the table of contents and the headings are set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the `scrbook` class and then use the macros `\frontmatter, \mainmatter, \backmatter`. If you use the first one just before the `\begin{document}` line then you can use easily chapters without troubles for add them at the toc. Something like this:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[]{}
\usepackage[]{}
\usepackage[]{}
    .
    .
    .
\usepackage[]{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\chapter{Preface}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\chapter{Three}
    .
    .
    .
\chapter{Last}

\appendix

\chapter{First appendix}
\chapter{Second appendix}

\backmatter

Bibliography

\end{document}
```

The schematic structure above shows the use of those macros available with the `scrbook` class that ease the use of different kind of chapters with or without numbers.